# How to sen gzipped content using PHP and Curl

Tags: php, curl

how can I SEND gzipped content using PHP and Curl? I read a lot of posts about reading gzipped content, but I need to send an gzipped XML request to a web service.

I tried this:

```
$url = 'http://212.170.xxx.xx/appservices/http/FrontendService';            

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array (
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1" ,
            "Content-Encoding: gzip"

            ) );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );   

    $comprimido = gzdeflate( 'xml_request=' .$xmlcontent );         

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,   $comprimido ); 

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    $RAWresponse = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
```

Also tried adding:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

and

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate');
```

but didn't work

Comment: Call `gzcompress()` to compress the data before posting it.

Comment: `CURLOPT_ENCODING` requests the server to compress the response, it has nothing to do with how the request is sent.